# Generate a new ID which is not taken

Tags: sql

```
DROP TABLE #ABC
CREATE TABLE #ABC (ID INT, Name VARCHAR (2))
INSERT INTO #ABC (ID, NAME)
VALUES (1,'01'),(1,'F5'),(1,'05'),(2,'08'),(2,'G4'),(3,'Y7'),(3,'18') 

drop table #XYZ
CREATE TABLE #XYZ (ID INT, Name char(20))
INSERT INTO #XYZ (ID,Name)
SELECT ID, SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), NEWID()) , '-', ''), 0, 3)  from #ABC

Select * from #XYZ
```

I want the process to create a new name which is already not taken by the same ID. in other words, same ID (say ID =1) can not have the same "Name" columns. This is just very few records but my real data is huge, I want system to generate only new Names with 2 characters in table#XYZ which are already not taken by the same ID in #ABC. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I added another temp table #DEF to hold the Names you're generating from NEWID().  It's a little clearer to use SUBSTRING('123456', 1, 2) to obtain the first two characters.  I also added a GROUP BY ID so that it will generate only one Name per ID.

Finally, I used a LEFT JOIN and a NULL match to look for #DEF entries that were not already present in #ABC.

```
DROP TABLE #ABC
CREATE TABLE #ABC (ID INT, Name VARCHAR (2))
INSERT INTO #ABC (ID, NAME)
VALUES (1,'01'),(1,'F5'),(1,'05'),(2,'08'),(2,'G4'),(3,'Y7'),(3,'18') 

DROP TABLE #DEF
CREATE TABLE #DEF (ID INT, Name char(20))
INSERT INTO #DEF (ID, Name)
SELECT ID, SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), NEWID()) , '-', ''), 1, 2) AS Name 
FROM #ABC
GROUP BY ID

DROP TABLE #XYZ
CREATE TABLE #XYZ (ID INT, Name char(20))
INSERT INTO #XYZ (ID, Name)
SELECT #DEF.ID, #DEF.Name 
FROM #DEF
LEFT JOIN #ABC ON #ABC.ID = #DEF.ID AND #ABC.Name = #DEF.Name
WHERE #ABC.ID IS NULL
GROUP BY #DEF.ID, #DEF.Name

SELECT * FROM #XYZ
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: It took care of the part where it is not generating IDs which already exist in #ABC but it is generating new IDs which are duplicates. say for ID = 1, It is generating '02' and '02' twice. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if you use NEWID() as a random number generator, and you generate a big pile of random numbers, you will get duplicates.  My code assumed that you are checking them one at a time before you insert them into #ABC.  I updated my answer to add GROUP BY #DEF.ID, #DEF.Name.  You could also use DISTINCT.  This should help eliminate your duplicates.

Comment: Loophole: If I use DISTINCT in table #DEF then we cant get all values if there is already same Name existing in #ABC. Lets say with ID=1 we have 50 records in #ABC, there are less than 50 records getting inserted in #DEF and hence in #XYZ. We want same number of records as in #ABC. Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to do that iteratively.  If you want to generate these "names" randomly, and then check that they obey some condition, you'll lose some along the way.  Check how many you still need, and then run it again, check how many you still need, and run it again, until you're done.

Comment: How exactly I will be able to achieve that? I get no solid fix from my friends or online forums. :(

Comment: You could use a [T/SQL loop such as WHILE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx)