# Unique ID base on other column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
DROP TABLE #ABC
CREATE TABLE #ABC (ID INT NOT NULL, Name VARCHAR (2) NOT NULL, name2 VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO #ABC (ID, NAME)
VALUES (1,'01'),(1,'F5'),(1,'05'),(1,'08'),(1,'02'), (1,'03'), (1,'04'), (1,'06'),(1,'07'),(1,'09'),(1,'10'),(1,'11'),(1,'12'),(1,'13'),(1,'14'),
(1,'15'),(1,'2D'),(1,'2E'),(1,'4B'),(1,'5F'),(1,'64'),(1,'73'),(1,'83'),(1,'88'),(1,'A9'),(1,'AC'),(1,'D0'),(1,'D7'),(1,'15'),(2,'76'),(2,'J5')
```

Script I am using to populate name2 (not working)

```
UPDATE A
SET name2 = SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), NEWID()) , '-', ''), 0, 3)
FROM #ABC AS A

select * from #ABC
```

So, I have table #ABC already populated with ID and NAME, I want to populate 'Name2' so that 'name2' should not have the same value as 'name' for the same ID. Example, for ID = 1 , all name2 values should be different than name values.
Thanks

Comment: Please **always** specify which concrete **database system** (and which version) you're using. SQL is just the query language - used by many databases .....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using SQL Server.  If so, you can make use of the `row_number()` function to append a unique identifier to the end of `name`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by name desc) as num
      from #abc t
     )
update toupdate
    set name2 = cast(num as varchar(2))
```

This will work for up to 99 duplicates for a given id.

Unfortunately, I don't have SQL Server available right now.  But here is an idea.  You can take the maximum value of name and then do arithmetic, base 36 (26 alpha and 10 numeric).  The result is something like this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by name desc) as seqnum,
             max(name) over (partition by id) as maxname,
             ((case when left(name, 1) between '0' and '9'
                    then ascii(left(name, 1))
                    else ascii(upper(left(name, 1))) - ascii('A')+10
               end) * 36 +
              (case when right(name, 1) between '0' and '9'
                    then ascii(right(name, 1))
                    else ascii(upper(right(name, 1))) - ascii('A')+10
               end)
             ) as namenum
      from #abc t
     )
update toupdate
    set name2 = (case when (namenum+seqnum)/36 < 10
                      then char(ascii('0')+((namenum+seqnum)/36))
                      else char(ascii('A')+((namenum+seqnum)/36) - 10)
                 end)+
                (case when ((namenum+seqnum)%36) < 10
                      then char(ascii('0')+((namenum+seqnum)%36))
                      else char(ascii('A')+((namenum+seqnum)%36) - 10)
                 end)
```

This finds the maximum name and then generates names bigger than that.  This assumes that you are using only alphabetic characters (upper case) and numbers.  It can fail if `name` takes on a value near the maximum possible value (`'ZZ'` in this case).

Comment: If you notice, the name and name2 is varchar(2), I need to use  SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), NEWID()) , '-', ''), 0, 3)
so that system would randomly pick up 2 digit values. and your query is not working :(

Comment: Thanks for editing your response but Its still not working as expected. I want two digit numbers in name2 and they should not be duplicates with name for same ID

Comment: @BhupinderSingh . . . It is going to be very hard to guarantee uniqueness unless you have something like a character that is not used in `name` or a list of all possible `name2` values.

Comment: unfortunately we do not have a list of all possible values, a system should be smart enough to auto populate this. I was thinking about grabiing the max value for each ID and add 1. for ex K5 for ID 1 and then name 2 should start from K6, K7..... Can you help writing something like this?

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425426/generate-a-new-id-which-is-not-taken this might help but this isnt working either.

Comment: You could use [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) to set up a database on SQL Server.